# AUTOHOTKEYS and how to press to buttons with one

Tags: autohotkey

i wanna use a script on ahk that when i press the key ''4'' it presses keys 4 + w (first 4 then W) how can i do this? is there a program for it except ahk that makes it easier?

Answer (score 2):

This script will first send the key 4 followed by w. `~` before key keeps its default behavior.

```
~4::
    Send, w
return 

;~ digit 4 on numpad
~Numpad4::
    Send, w
return
```

Comment: so question is there a way i can add a thrird key to this script. like press 4 and trigger 4 W D. THANKS FOR HELP BTW APPRECIATE IT

Comment: also can i use a key to activete and disable the script. for expample use caps lock on and off  to enable disable ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap):
`~4::w`

[`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) makes it so the hotkeys isn't consumed when fired.
And if you wanted to add more keys, such as numpad4 like in the other answer, you'd do it nice and short like this:

```
~Numpad4::
~4::w
```